# GNU parallell in Sun Grid Engine cluster(starcluser)?

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel, sungridengine

I've 5 nodes (each has 64 processors) cluster set-up from starcluster with OpenMPI and Sun Grid Engine installed. I use gnu parallel to utilize all the 320 cpu but the cpu utilization is very low and not using all cpus.Any suggestion would be appreciated.

#

submit batch

```
qsub -pe orte 320 job_TFs.sh
```

#

Updated code I've tried/used:  filename: job_TFs.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -N test
#$ -S /bin/sh
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y

export WDIR=/home/xxx/software/xtx_v2.1
cd $WDIR;

parallel="parallel -S node001,node002,node003,node004,node005 --wd $WDIR --joblog process.log --resume"

$PARALLEL -a test.lst sh run_TFs.sh {}
```

job_TFs.sh have :

```
i=$1

TMP_DIR=/home/xxx/software/xxx_v2.1/$i
mkdir -p $TMP_DIR

cd $TMP_DIR/

mk=$(echo "$i" | cut -d- -f1-2) 
nk=$(echo "$i" | cut -d- -f3-6) 

cp /home/xxx/TF_data/_tf/$mk.pdb $TMP_DIR/
cp /home/xxx/TF_data/_tf/$nk.pdb $TMP_DIR/


/home/xxx/software/xxxx_v2.1/xxxx -s1 $mk.pdb -s1cf $mk-cf.pdb -s1ss $mk-ss.pdb -s2 $nk.pdb -s2cf $nk-cf.pdb -s2ss $nk-ss.pdb >> /home/xxx/TF_data/xxxx_tf/scores/$i.out
$TMP_DIR/../
rm -rf $TMP_DIR
```

system info:

```
 qconf -sp orte

pe_name            orte
slots              321
user_lists         NONE
xuser_lists        NONE
start_proc_args    /bin/true
stop_proc_args     /bin/true
allocation_rule    $fill_up
control_slaves     TRUE
job_is_first_task  FALSE
urgency_slots      min
accounting_summary FALSE
```

[image: ssh to node001 and top shows this :]

Comment: The shell variable `$PARALLEL` is used by GNU Parallel. Consider using `$parallel` instead, or used `$PARALLEL` as intended (namely for options to GNU Parallel. So you basically just have to remove the command `parallel` from the string).

Comment: Are they waiting for disk I/O? If you can run fewer and these will run at 100% then this is a good indication you are I/O-starved.

Comment: Will this work ?

parallel -j $JOBS_PER_NODE -S node001,node002,node003,node004,node005 --wd $WDIR --joblog process_glosa.log --resume -a test.lst sh run_TF.sh {}

Comment: @OleTange Plz checked the updated one. Still not utilizing 100% cpu. Any suggestion, thanks

Comment: @OleTange Could you more specific? how would I use n=1 job in the parallel command? Should test -a test.lst contains one task? and try more after? 
Btw, the list has ~300 million and each task finishes less than a min. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First we need to rule out that this is caused by I/O.

n=1

Try running n tasks in parallel on a single server (`parallel -j`*n*). Does that use n CPUs at 100%?

Yes: n=n+1, try again.

No: How big is n?

Comment: Any idea?suggestion?